# How to fix "Configuration system failed to initialize/Root element is missing" error when loading config file?

Tags: c#, config

I got this error in my c# windows application: "Configuration system failed to initialize".

It was working fine. Suddenly I got this exception. It shows inner exception detail as "Root element is missing". (C:\Users\company\AppData\Local\Clickbase_Corp_Sverige_AB\TouchStation.vshost.exe_Url_no1nets4fg3oy2p2q2pnwgulbvczlv33\1.1.0.12\user.config)"}.This happens when I try to get values from Settings.cs class.

In program.cs file the below code is written

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
                Properties.Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();                
            }
```

And calls settings.cs class where the below code throws above exception

```
    [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("True")]

    public bool CallUpgrade {
        get {
            return ((bool)(this["CallUpgrade"]));
        }
        set {
            this["CallUpgrade"] = value;
        }
    }
```

The below is my entire app.config

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="TouchStation.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="TouchStation.TouchStation" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="TouchStation.TouchStation" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="SitesInfo" type="TouchServer.SitesInfoSectionHandler,TouchServerLib" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebRoot" value="webroot" />
    <add key="TempDir" value="temp" />
    <add key="ServerPort" value="9338" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <userSettings>
    <TouchStation.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Site" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="StationID" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Location" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="ShutdownTime" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0000</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ReportStatusEvery" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SynchronizeEvery" serializeAs="String">
        <value>10</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultUsername" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="WatchdogTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>60</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RebootOnTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="AnonymousLogin" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RefID" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="AutoStart" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DemoMode" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UnlockPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value>needle</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SynchronizerUsername" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="SynchronizerPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="RunClientApplications" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="MapID" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServerName" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="CallUpgrade" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServerPort" serializeAs="String">
        <value>9338</value>
      </setting>
    </TouchStation.Properties.Settings>
    <TouchStation.TouchStation>
      <setting name="ServerURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="Site" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="StationID" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Location" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="ShutdownTime" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="ReportStatusEvery" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SynchronizeEvery" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="HideMouse" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="HideDesktopOnStart" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultUsername" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultPassword" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
      <setting name="LogServerPort" serializeAs="String">
        <value>9050</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="WatchdogTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>60</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RebootOnTimeout" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="AnonymousLogin" serializeAs="String">
        <value>True</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="RefID" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </TouchStation.TouchStation>
  </userSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
    <TouchStation.TouchStation>
      <setting name="ClientSettingsURL" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </TouchStation.TouchStation>
  </applicationSettings>
  <SitesInfo>
    <sites>
      <site Name="Local" FullName="Local Site" DatabaseConnectionString="Data\local.db" />
    </sites>
  </SitesInfo>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

can anyone help me in this?

Thank You.

Regards,

jennie

Comment: And what's the content of C:\Users\company\AppData\Local\Clickbase_Corp_Sverige_AB\TouchStation.vshost.exe_Url_no1nets4fg3oy2p2q2pnwgulbvczlv33\1.1.0.12\user.config?

Comment: is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  there ?

Comment: Actually i dont know why this path C:\Users\company\AppData\Local\Clickbase_Corp_Sverige_AB\TouchStation.vshost.exe_­Url_no1nets4fg3oy2p2q2pnwgulbvczlv33\1.1.0.12\user.config is showing in exception.coz ther is no such path and my application was running perfectly.suddenly i got this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the `XmlException` entitled Root element is missing means the XML document  (The config file here) you're trying to load is not formatted properly, more exactly it's missing the root node.

Each XML file must have a root element / node which encloses all the other elements.

Your file must look like the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
            type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System,
            Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Settings>
        </WindowsFormsApplication.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could be the problem, but `<?xml ... ?>` is _not_ called the root-node. It is a processing instruction. `<configuration>` is the root.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the answer by Akram Shahda: I had the same kind of problem (configuration system failed to initialize / root element is missing). The .config file in the AppData folder was empty. The problem was solved by deleting the .config file in the AppData folder.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case if any one reads This :

For me i solved the issue by just going to the user.config location, for this question it is :

> (C:\Users\company\AppData\Local\Clickbase_Corp_Sverige_AB\TouchStation.vshost.exe_Url_no1nets4fg3oy2p2q2pnwgulbvczlv33\1.1.0.12\user.config)"

I deleted the config file and restarted visual studio and it worked.

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In console app you should allocate < startup/> section after < configSections/>

Answer (score 1):

In general, the "Configuration system failed to initialize" issue is likely caused by invalid XML structure in the app.config. I've stumbled on this from time to time when attempting to port code from a "test bed" config file to a service app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the connectionStrings node was declared twice.

Answer (score 1):

One of our customers got this error "Configuration system failed to initialize" while attempting to FTP from a C# project.  The user was NOT an admin.

Our techie customer investigated and found, using ProcMon under a non-admin account, that the resource used by this process was the .NET machine.config file.
(c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config)

Our customer granted local users modify rights to just this config file, and it immediately resolved the issue. 
(They do not allow users to be admins, so this was necessary.)

So if the above answer doesn't work for you, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue today. I was trying to compile a visual studio solution and could not.

The issue was that the configuration file had xml name space configured. Visual studio / msbuild had been happily compiling with this namespace included in the application configuration for many years, which makes this error a bit strange.

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

But once removing the namespace and visual studio / msbuild were happy once again.

```
<configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    con = new OleDbConnection(config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["connectionStr"].ConnectionString.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after check all, the problem was in the last part of the App.config, where a Log4Net configuration statement produce the error.

Delete all the extra in App.config and start to debug.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="[Application Name].Settings.Client" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>    
    </configSections>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
  <applicationSettings>
  <[Application Name].Settings.Client>
    <setting name="IDClient" serializeAs="String">
    <value>6</value>
    </setting>
  </[Application Name].Settings.Client>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

for .Net Core with Graphviz:

> ```
> <configSections>
>     <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
>         type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System,
>         Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
>     </sectionGroup>
> </configSections>
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="graphVizLocation" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin" />
> </appSettings> </configuration>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I took a copy of the user.config file, put it under the resource and took a backup in the application with the default values. If the user.config file is not where it should be, I solved this problem by creating this file and typing it in.

```
if (!File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration (ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath)) //user.config path
{

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration (ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath))  //configuration root is added
   {
     writer.WriteStartElement("configuration");                    
     writer.WriteEndElement();
     writer.Flush();
   }
File.WriteAllText(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration (ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath, Properties.Resources.user);

Application.Restart(); //restart application
Environment.Exit(0);

}
```